# Kendo Grid Date Sort not working properly with M/d/yy

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have scoured the interwebs and have not been able to conclude why this is not working as I see in so many demos. I must be missing something simple... except most examples don't use the M/d/yy format for the dates. When I use this format, my data ends up with a column like:

```
1/19/14
10/05/14
2/02/14
5/15/14
```

Any ideas? You can see I have my date column template commented out because it wasn't actually doing anything that made a difference.

**Here's my Grid:**

```
$("#mygiving-details-grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields:{
                        date: {type: "date"},
                        fund: {type: "string"},
                        desc: {type: "string"},
                        name: {type: "string"},
                        type: {type: "string"},
                        amt: {type: "number"}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        sortable: true,
        toolbar: "<span>Filter goes here</span>",
        columns: [{
            field: "date",
            title: myGivingModel.local.giving.date,
            // format: "{0:"+systemDateFormat+"}",
            // template: "#= kendo.toString(date, '"+systemDateFormat+"') #",
            width: 100
        }, {
            field: "fund",
            title: myGivingModel.local.giving.fund
        }, {
            field: "desc",
            title: myGivingModel.local.giving.description
        }, {
            field: "name",
            title: myGivingModel.local.giving.name
        }, {
            field: "type",
            title: myGivingModel.local.giving.type
        }, {
            field: "amt",
            title: myGivingModel.local.giving.amount,
            attributes:{
                style:"text-align:right;"
            },
            format: "{0:c}"
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Can you tell me what date format you need in your grid? Because in my opinion your dates is in M/d/yy as you've told. (M-one/two digit month, d - two digit day, yy - two digit year).

Comment: Well, the `systemDateFormat` variable brings the date format back from the server for use throughout. So it very well could be a handful of different formats...

Answer (score 0):

When using https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx this should just work fine. I just changed in the Scripts\common.js this code:

```
var _DefaultDateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
// into this
var _DefaultDateFormat = "M/dd/yy";
```

and the sorting works as expected.

Comment: I would sure prefer to not use 3rd party plugins as I have seen this functionality work on vanilla Kendo platform stuff.

Comment: Correct. I just wanted to point out that the problem is maybe located at the server-side, maybe the date-objects are not really interpreted as a date, but as a string on the server.